# Way to handle exception threw by Action passed as parameter to function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

```cs
  try
    {
        if (productDto.Images != null)
        {
            productDto.ImagesUrls = new List<string>();
            foreach (var image in productDto.Images)
            {
                var name = await _imageWriter.UploadImage(image);
                productDto.ImagesUrls.Add(name);
            }

            await _repository.RemoveProductImages(productDto.Id);
            await _repository.SetNewImagesPathsForProduct(productDto.Id, productDto.ImagesUrls);
        }

        var result =  await base.UpdateAsync(productDto, commands, async (ProductDto dto, bool name) =>
                await CustomValidationWithUserRole(productDto, true));
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        foreach (var imagePath in productDto.ImagesUrls)
            await _imageWriter.RemoveFile(imagePath);

        var oldImageUrls = productDto.ImagesUrls;

        await _repository.SetNewImagesPathsForProduct(productFromDb.Id, oldImageUrls);

        throw;
    }
```

As per the code snippet, I'm passing a Function which return void but it can throw an exception when one of model properties are invalid or some entity doesn't exists in db (validation).

The problem occurs when this method (CustomValidationWithUserRole) throws an exception. It's not catch-ed in this try-catch statement.

How can I catch this exception and pass it further to controller (which is one layer above)?

Below are the places where I'm invoking this function:

```
    public async Task<UDto> UpdateAsync(UDto dto, List<Command> commands = null, Action<UDto, bool> customDtoEntityValidation = null)
    {
        var updatedModel = default(TModel);

        try
        {
            await DtoSingleValidate(dto, customDtoEntityValidation, true);
            var model = await ConvertDtoToModel(dto);
            updatedModel = await _repository.UpdateAsync(model);
            var updatedDto = await ConvertModelToDto(updatedModel);

            SetIds(commands, updatedDto);
            await SendCommands(commands);
            return updatedDto;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (updatedModel != default(TModel))
            {
                await _repository.DeleteAsync(updatedModel);
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

    private async Task DtoSingleValidate(UDto dto, Action<UDto, bool> customDtoEntityValidation, bool update)
    {
        if (customDtoEntityValidation == null)
        {
            await DtoValidation(dto, update);
        }
        else
        {
            customDtoEntityValidation.Invoke(dto, update);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the `Action` you're passing is asynchronous and nothing is awaiting the result. The action is executed as fire and forget and there is nothing to catch the exception as the caller has already moved on.

You need to change the type of `customDtoEntityValidation` to be a `Func<UDto, bool, Task>` and `await` the result appropriately.